# JPA: How to map VARCHAR column containg dates to DATE format?

Tags: date, jpa, eclipselink

I have to read dates from a database using JPA. I'm using EclipseLink and MySQL.
The date is stored in the database as varchar(10) in the format YYYY-MM-DD. It's not possible changing the database column type. 
Is there a way to map this column to some dates type (DATE, CALENDAR)?
Is it possible to force convertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EclipseLink you can use a Converter.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#CHDEHJEB

A simple @TypeConverter may work, otherwise you can create your own Converter.